# Bookmark Title Page

Tags: bookmarks

Does anyone know how to hyperref the title page of a pdf file? I mean I want my title to appear as the highest level in the bookmaks and the sections will be the next level etc so that the bookmark will look like a tree with branches. Only the sections appear at the moment and stand on their own. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I usually do this:

```
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pdfbookmark[0]{\@title}{title}
\makeatother

\maketitle
```

This uses the title defined by the `\title` command but you can use something else (then the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are not needed).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the `bookmark` package. This can be implemented in the following way:

At the top of your title-page code you put the command `\hypertarget{TitlePage}{}`. This creates the target/label your bookmark will point towards.

Then, insert your code for the title page.

After the `\maketitle` command you simply add `\bookmark[dest=TitlePage]{Title Page}`.

For my thesis, I made a separate file for my title page and used the `titlepage` environment, then included that file into the core .tex document like this:

```
\hypertarget{TitlePage}{}
\include{TitlePage}
\bookmark[dest=TitlePage]{Title Page}
```

The `bookmark` package offers a number of other interesting features, including formatting commands for the bookmarks. One that I found interesting for a thesis is the `numbered` format that can be loaded as a package option. This option adds the numbers of chapters/sections/subsections to the bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `\hypertarget`-command. I've been looking for that for ages.