# Hyperref doesn't produce bookmarks for title page nor the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

As stated, hyperref doesn't produce in the bookmarks titlepage nor table of contents. To be more specific, I have a 8 chapters, with over 50 sections, and lots of cross-references. ALL of that is produced perfectly and flawlessly. But when the final PDF is compiled the bookmarks start at PREFACE and not at TABLE OF CONTENTS or TITLE PAGE as I wish they did.

```
\documentclass[leqno, letterpaper, 10 pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle={Fundamentos de C\'alculo},
        pdfsubject={C\'alculo diferencial},
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        bookmarksopen=true,
        bookmarksopenlevel=1,
        colorlinks=true,
        citecolor=black,
        filecolor=black,
        linkcolor=black,
        urlcolor=black,
        pdfstartview=Fit,
        pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
        pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight
    }

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\scshape \huge Fundamentos de c\'{a}lculo. \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape \large \textsc{Parte I. Preliminares del c\'{a}lculo.} \par}
    {\scshape Capítulos del 1 al 4. \par}
    {\scshape \large \textsc{Parte II. Desarrollo del c\'{a}lculo diferencial.} \par}
    {\scshape Capítulos del 5 al 8. \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \vfill
    {\large Mayo de 2018. \par}
    \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest to use package `bookmarks`. But you have to set hypertargets as targets of the bookmark links. For the TOC you have to ensure that the target is on its first page.

```
\documentclass[leqno, letterpaper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{bookmark}% loads hyperref too
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle={Fundamentos de C\'alculo},
        pdfsubject={C\'alculo diferencial},
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        bookmarksopen=true,
        bookmarksopenlevel=1,
        hidelinks,% remove border and color
        pdfstartview=Fit,
        pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
        pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight
    }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \hypertarget{titlepage}{}% set the hypertarget
    \bookmark[dest=titlepage,level=chapter]{Title Page}% add the bookmark
    {\scshape \huge Fundamentos de c\'{a}lculo. \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape \large \textsc{Parte I. Preliminares del c\'{a}lculo.} \par}
    {\scshape Capítulos del 1 al 4. \par}
    {\scshape \large \textsc{Parte II. Desarrollo del c\'{a}lculo diferencial.} \par}
    {\scshape Capítulos del 5 al 8. \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \vfill
    {\large Mayo de 2018. \par}
    \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
\end{titlepage}

\cleardoublepage% ensure that the hypertarget is on the same page as the TOC heading
\hypertarget{toc}{}% set the hypertarget
\bookmark[dest=toc,level=chapter]{\contentsname}% add the bookmark
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Bibliographic review}

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the `bookmark`[package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark), as it does add a lot of functionalities.

My answer was based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11867/customize-pdf-bookmarks) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34970/bookmark-title-page).

[image: titlepage and TOC bookmarks]

```
\documentclass[leqno, letterpaper, 10 pt]{book}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle={Fundamentos de C\'alculo},
        pdfsubject={C\'alculo diferencial},
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        bookmarksopen=true,
        bookmarksopenlevel=1,
        colorlinks=true,
        citecolor=black,
        filecolor=black,
        linkcolor=black,
        urlcolor=black,
        pdfstartview=Fit,
        pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
        pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight
    }

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\scshape \huge Fundamentos de c\'{a}lculo. \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape \large \textsc{Parte I. Preliminares del c\'{a}lculo.} \par}
    {\scshape Capítulos del 1 al 4. \par}
    {\scshape \large \textsc{Parte II. Desarrollo del c\'{a}lculo diferencial.} \par}
    {\scshape Capítulos del 5 al 8. \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \vfill
    {\large Mayo de 2018. \par}
    \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
\bookmark[dest=TitlePage]{Title Page}  
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\bookmark[dest=tocpage,level=-1]{Contents}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Bibliographic review}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works well though the other answer is slightly better.